# quarkus running in dev mode does not see pom dependecy

Tags: java, quarkus

I am trying to write a quarkus application with a json rest interface which should have a dependency on an external library. I'd like to call some methods from this library in my rest implementation.

So, I started from a simple quarkus rest application [getting-started](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started)

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create -DprojectGroupId=org.acme -DprojectArtifactId=getting-started -DclassName="org.acme.getting.started.GreetingResource" -Dpath="/hello
```

then I added my external library (called test-library) as dependency to the generated pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.examples</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-library</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

The external library pom.xml looked like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test Library</name>
    <description>Some description</description>

    <properties>
        <!-- Override default JAVA target version -->
        <project.compiler.source>11</project.compiler.source>
        <project.compiler.target>11</project.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I built and installed the external library (locally) by running

```
~/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin/mvn compile install -s ~/.m2sb/settings.xml
```

successfully, then I tried to start the quarkus greeting app in the Quarkus dev mode

```
~/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin/mvn compile quarkus:dev -s ~/.m2sb/settings.xml
```

where I got an error

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:dev (default-cli) @ getting-started ---
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Failed to create the application model for org.acme:getting-started::jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:150)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:63)
Caused by: io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Failed to create the application model for org.acme:getting-started::jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapAppModelFactory.resolveAppModel(BootstrapAppModelFactory.java:320)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.QuarkusBootstrap.bootstrap(QuarkusBootstrap.java:163)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:143)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.BootstrapMavenException: Failed to resolve dependencies for org.acme:getting-started:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.MavenArtifactResolver.resolveManagedDependencies(MavenArtifactResolver.java:273)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.BootstrapAppModelResolver.doResolveModel(BootstrapAppModelResolver.java:186)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.BootstrapAppModelResolver.resolveManagedModel(BootstrapAppModelResolver.java:152)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapAppModelFactory.resolveAppModel(BootstrapAppModelFactory.java:306)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.examples:test-library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:357)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.MavenArtifactResolver.resolveManagedDependencies(MavenArtifactResolver.java:269)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.examples:test-library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:340)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.examples:test-library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:414)
        ... 9 more
```

So, for some reason the quarkus in the dev mode was not able to find the test-library artifact which was stored installed / stores locally in the maven repo.

By the way, also I tried to run maven compile install on the greeting app and the artifact of external library was found and maven was successful.

So, it looked like like quarkus internal class loader was not able to find the external artifact. Is this expected behavior ? Do I have to make my external library as a quarkus extension to get loaded at the quarkus dev mode ?

After further experimenting, I got this working yet both - the quarkus greeting application and the test-library had to be changed into maven sub-modules under a common maven parent. Then it located the test-library in the quarkus dev mode at start up. This was a bit strange and I did not understand why this was so different to the previous scenario.

I guess I am missing some basic knowledge about the usage of already exiting libraries in the quarkus apps.

Comment: Here's 2 things I'd investigate first. 1. Maybe the problem is that the dependency is a `SNAPSHOT`? Try using a fixed (release-like) version and see. 2. Maybe you use a non-default local Maven repository configured in your `settings.xml` and Quarkus doesn't know about it? Try using the default local Maven repository (`~/.m2/repository`) and default `settings.xml` (`~/.m2/settings.xml`) and see. Now -- for sure what you observe seems to be a bug, the 2 options above are just ideas what to investigate. Filing a bug report in Quarkus is probably a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. So, I tried the first one with the <version>0.0.2</version> of the test-library and that did not help. Then, I tired the second option where completely removed my default ./m2 directory and created new one with very simple settings.xml and that worked. Conclusion: So, it looked like when running classic mvn compile install -s ~/.m2sb/settings.xml then it used the correct m2sb maven directory, however as soon as quarkus:dev was added it was trying to use default m2 directory. This was visible as it started to download all project dependencies into m2 directory.

Comment: Basically adding quarkus:dev goal triggers ignoring option -s ~/.m2sb/settings.xml I guess that is a bug as it always expects default m2 location. You saved a lot of my time thanks for your help.

Comment: Yea I think you localized the problem. Opening an issue in the Quarkus bug tracker would be very nice!

Comment: yep, I have just done at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/17947

Answer (score 0):

Does your `~/.m2sb/settings.xml` contain proper `localRepository` path?
I couldn't reproduce it. In fact, if I install the `test-library` to the default `~/.m2/repository` and not in `~/.m2sb/repository`, the app will fail to launch in dev mode because the `test-library` would missing. Installing it into `~/.m2sb/repository` actually fixes it.

Comment: Thanks very much for looking into this. I have looked at my original `~/.m2sb/settings.xml` and there was `<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2sb/repository</localRepository>`, so that was not definitely pointing to ./m2 . However, I am going to try to simulate it again with a completely new maven repo placed at different location than the default one to see if I had a problem within my environment setup. I will let you know. (probably in late evening). Cheers.